# ¿Cómo ajusto el tamaño del gráfico de coordenadas con datos grandes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, gráficas, regresión-lineal

estoy intentando graficar una serie de puntos tomados con una estación de topografía

```
ID  Este    Norte
0   1   487678.609  1106046.370
1   2   487684.670  1106043.161
2   3   487704.007  1106032.270
3   4   487707.617  1106043.045
4   5   487726.483  1106035.725
```

A la serie Este, le puse X y a la serie Norte le puse Y.

Usé el siguiente código para mostrar los puntos en un gráfico de coordenadas:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [100,50]

plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

plt.plot(x, y, 'r*')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])

for i, j in zip(x, y):
   plt.text(i, j+0.5, '({}, {})'.format(i, j))

plt.show()
```

Pero la salida del código me muestra el siguiente problema:

> UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. The left and right margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations.
> fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

**ValueError: Image size of 453618050x150323576 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.Figure size 7200x3600 with 1 Axes**

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que python represente gráficamente estos puntos?
¿Debo transformar la data a una serie escalable para python?

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema está en `plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])` en combinación con `plt.text(i, j+0.5, '({}, {})'.format(i, j))`

En `plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])`, estás configurando que la gráfica vaya de 0 a 6 en el eje X y de 0 a 20 en el eje Y, los valores que quieres graficar son mucho más grandes y estarían fuera del área que configuras en tu `axis()` por lo que al configurar los textos estos están fuera del área de la gráfica y por eso te aparece el error

Si comentas la línea del `axis()` entonces el área del gráfico se configura automáticamente utilizando tus datos como referencia y el texto quedará dentro del área del gráfico

Ejemplo (Utilicé tus datos en sample2.csv para hacer la gráfica):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [12,8]

plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

x = df['Este']
y = df['Norte']

plt.plot(x, y, 'r*')
#plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    plt.text(i, j+0.5, '({}, {})'.format(i, j))

plt.show()
```

Esto devuelve la siguiente gráfica (Nota, reduje el tamaño de la gráfica a 12, 8 porque 100, 50 es muy grande y los puntos no se ven):

[image: Gráfica]